# Stuck on AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'reindex' when trying to save workbook in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I can't figure this one out.  It's complaining about the wb.save() line.  I have no idea what's causing it after banging my head on this.  I suspect it has something to do with trying to open a blank sheet and saving it after doing stuff with formatting, but I can't imagine what I'm doing there that's causing this problem.  It worked fine when I opened an existing spreadsheet and did manipulations, but that required me to have an existing spreadsheet in the first place.  Here, I'm trying to start a new spreadsheet from scratch.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from lxml import etree 
import os, codecs
import imageFilesSub
import re
import openpyxl, lxml
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string

homeEnv = 0  # 1 - home, 0 - work

if homeEnv:
    filesDir = r'K:\Users\Johnny\My Documents\_World_of_Waterfalls\Website\tier 2 pages\tier 3 pages\tier 4 pages'
    filesOutDir = r'K:\Users\Johnny\My Documents\_World_of_Waterfalls\WordPressSite'
else:
    filesDir = r'..\old_travelblog_writeups'
    filesOutDir = r'./'


# First get the list of files to parse
filesInDir = os.listdir(filesDir)
filesToParse = []
for file in filesInDir:
    if ('travel-blog' in file) and (file.endswith('-template.html')):
        filesToParse.append(file)

# Open up the travelBlog spreadsheet and set it up
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active
sheet.name = "travelBlog List"
sheet['A1'].value = 'Blog No.'
sheet['B1'].value = 'Title'
sheet['C1'].value = 'Category'
sheet['D1'].value = 'Keyword Tags'
sheet['E1'].value = 'Excerpt'
sheet['F1'].value = 'Featured Image Filename'
sheet['G1'].value = 'Featured Image Alt Text'
sheet['H1'].value = 'Start Date'
sheet['I1'].value = 'End Date'
sheet['J1'].value = 'Old Web Address'
sheet['K1'].value = 'New Travel Blog Body Filename'
sheet['L1'].value = 'Old Travel Blog Template to parse'
sheet.freeze_panes = 'C2'
sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = 10
sheet.column_dimensions['H','I'] = 20
sheet.column_dimensions['B','F','J','K','L'] = 40
sheet.column_dimensions['D','E'] = 50
from openpyxl.styles import Font
headerFontObj = Font(name='Arial', bold=True)
for col in range(1,sheet.max_column):
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=col).font = headerFontObj

wb.save('travelBlogParsed.xlsx')
```

Thanks in advance,
Johnny

Answer (score 9):

I figured it out.  The issue was the following lines:

```
sheet.column_dimensions['H','I'] = 20
sheet.column_dimensions['B','F','J','K','L'] = 40
sheet.column_dimensions['D','E'] = 50
```

First of all, apparently, you can't use the column_dimensions method on a vector.  The argument must be a string.  Second, these lines were missing the .width attribute.  So those lines should have been:

```
sheet.column_dimensions['H'].width = 20
sheet.column_dimensions['I'].width = 20
sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 40
...
sheet.column_dimensions['E'].width = 50
```

Comment: You are my saver. I missed .width in one place and the error is "Attribute Error: float has no attribute 'reindex'... " I could never find out this bug myself. I think they should work on this error message because it obviously shouldn't allow people to do it without .width in the first place.

Comment: I'm so glad that this answer came up as soon as I googled "openpyxl AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'reindex'". It saved me from the same frustration that you already experienced and solved