# Cannot write output excel file with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, windowserror

I have been working on a script using openpyxl that has been working properly up until yesterday when I accidentally closed my GUI mid-process. Since that time my script has been unable to save to a new excel file in any directory. I am using PyCharm as my IDE. Whenever I run the script I receive the following error:

> WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\users\**username**\appdata\local\temp\openpyxl.izzaxe'

This was working properly so I do not believe it is an issue with my code, but I have included a snippet below:

```
wb = load_workbook(filename=r'PATH TO SOME EXCEL FILE')
header = wb['Sheet1'][1:1]
listheader = []
for h in listheader:
    listheader.append(h.value)
wb['Sheet2'].append(listheader)
wb.save(filename=r'PATH TO A DIFFERENT EXCEL FILE'
```

I have closed PyCharm and re-opened but still receive the error message. I have also navigated to **c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp** and deleted the file causing the block, but when I re-run my script a new openpyxl file with a different extension becomes generated in the same directory and blocks my script from saving the new file. I currently have 5 different openpyxl temp files with random extensions in my **appdata\local\temp** directory

I have also restarted my computer and uninstalled and reinstalled openpyxl with pip both with no success. I have also attempted to run the script through CMD and with IDLE, but I receive the same error message.

I am using Python 2.7 which is required as it is the default python installation that comes with ArcGIS and I need access to the arcpy module's metadata functionality which has no Python 3 equivalent. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the Task Manager (ctrl-alt-delete) and forcing those processes closed?

Comment: I have ended Pycharm under Apps in Task Manager which included the following subtasks: Pycharm, Filesystem events processor, and Console Window Host. Unfortunately I still receive the error. I appreciate your help

Comment: Did you check the processes tab for instances of Excel running?

Comment: I did check for excel instances and none were found. It seems to be complaining more about a particular file in appdata\local\temp entitled openpyxl with a random extension value. A new version of this file is generated each time I run my script. E.g. "openpyxl.jau0hu". It's 0 KB.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this was actually being caused by a portion of my code. I was defining column dimensions for my output as follows:

```
wb['Sheet1'].column_dimensions['A'] = 100
wb['Sheet1'].column_dimensions['C'] = 50
wb['Sheet1'].column_dimensions['D'] = 50
wb['Sheet1'].column_dimensions['E'] = 150
wb['Sheet1'].column_dimensions['F'] = 150
```

Not including the width attribute was what was causing the script to fail. Revising the above to the following fixed my problem:

```
wb['Sheet1'].column_dimensions['A'].width = 100
wb['Sheet1'].column_dimensions['C'].width = 50
wb['Sheet1'].column_dimensions['D'].width = 50
wb['Sheet1'].column_dimensions['E'].width = 150
wb['Sheet1'].column_dimensions['F'].width = 150
```

This may be a duplicate of the following thread where I found my answer:
[Stuck on AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'reindex' when trying to save workbook in openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488595/stuck-on-attributeerror-int-object-has-no-attribute-reindex-when-trying-to)